# Has <xsl:package> been deprecated in XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

This used to work years ago, but not anymore. It says:

"Unbound namespace prefix: "xsl:package" at line 1 column 36"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:package name="P" version="9.0">
   <xsl:global-context-item as="item()" use="optional" streamable="true" />
   <xsl:expose component="template" names="T1 T2" visibility="public"/>
   <xsl:use-package name="P2" version="10.0">
      <xsl:accept component="template" names="T1 T2" visibility="public"/>
      <xsl:override>
          <xsl:template match="object">
             <dummy/>
          </xsl:template>  
      </xsl:override>
   </xsl:use-package>
  
   <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:import href="a.xsl"/>
     <xsl:include href="b.xsl" use-when="system-property('xsl:vendor')='vendorX'"/>
     <xsl:template match="person">
        <override>
           <xsl:apply-imports/>    
        </override>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="animal">
        <override>
           <xsl:next-match/>    
        </override>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
</xsl:package>
```

Comment: `xsl:package` was introduced in XSLT 3, not deprecated. It is not clear with what version or implementation you worked when you say "years ago", I would suggest to start with the official spec released in 2017 or with e.g. Saxon's documentation: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/using-xsl/compiling/packages.html

Comment: I consider it highly unlikely that a line using a prefixed element like `<xsl:package name="P" version="9.0">` without declaring a namespace for that prefix `xsl` did ever work with any XSLT processor, as that input code just breaks any XML with namespaces well-formedness rules.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I gave that example in a book I wrote about 8 years ago. Apparently, the W3C draft had not been finalized. My knowledge of XSLT has become somewhat rusty since then. I am trying to update the book now. Practical examples have been somewhat hard to find. Anyway, you have been very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you run your examples at that time? Anyway, the current spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#packages has all the details and with e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#packages-csv-library-example an example. On the other hand, to use packages with a particular processor, you will need to read its documentation, too, to see how to load/link packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not with the local name "package", the problem is the undeclared namespace prefix `xsl`. An XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document, and this isn't because of the undeclared namespace prefix.

Another problem here is the nesting of `xsl:stylesheet` within `xsl:package`. That may correspond to the syntax defined in some early draft of XSLT 3.0, but it's not allowed in the final specification.